# In eclipse debugger, variables view, can I change "Value" value

Tags: eclipse, debugging, variables, view

I wonder if there is a way to change what we see in Value in Variables view in eclipse debugger?
For example instead of `"ObjectClass (id=94)"` I would like to see what that object `toString()` method returns, is it possible?

(I know that in "Expressions" we can add `variable.toString()` and it will show it, but I must add it manually, over time is tedious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using your own debug **detailed Formatters**. Check [here](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli) that the **Person**  object is changed from **Person(id=38)** to **Name=John Surname=Smit**.

Also refer this [link](http://www.robertwloch.net/2012/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-detail-formatter/).